# How to add element with "position absolute" on a jframe?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, absolute, jlayeredpane

Actually this is my code :

```
private void createDisplay(){
    frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setFocusable(false);

    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.pack();
}
```

And it's working to put on my screen my game (The game is draw in the canvas).
I need to add some other elements at the front of the screen like JButtons for exemples.
I tried "JLayeredPane" Like this :

```
    private void createDisplay(){
    frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    //layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener((MouseMotionListener) this);
    frame.add(layeredPane);

    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setFocusable(false);

    layeredPane.add(canvas,new Integer(10));
    frame.pack();
}
```

But when i launch the programm, i don"t see the canvas, only the layeredPane :/
Anny idea ? thx for all.
PS : IF you have an other sollution i'm ok, i just need to keep my JPanel.

Comment: Move `frame.setVisible(true);` to the last line (after `frame.pack`)

Comment: Also, this isn't going to work the way you think it should, `Canvas` is a heavy weight component and won't play nicely with Swing (light weight) containers, as it has z-ordering issues...

Comment: Oh, and Swing doesn't play nicely when you use active rendering techniques like `BufferStrategy`

Comment: Thx but don't works :/ Ok for your avertissement, have you an idea to solve my problem ? To put a JButton at te front of the screen, on the canvas ?

Comment: Can I assume `Canvas` is a `java.awt.Canvas`?  If not, Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  Otherwise you're kind of screwed and you will need to implement your own "buttons"

Comment: Yes you can, i imported java.awt.Canvas :D

Comment: Okay, you're going to have to do it the hard way, rendering your own graphics/painting your own buttons